# Дистрибутив с установкой не только из оффициальных репозиториев

Tags: python, xfce, debian

Всем ку.

Хочу научится питону с qt-гуй под никсами.  Декстоп на xfce. Установил дебиан - это отцы посоветовали - однако когда установил на нем питон 2.7 (изначально там 2.6), все по шпаргалге с офф.  сайта, вроде изначально все ок, но не все пакеты из дебиановских репов хотят с ним работать,  к примеру, иде ерик.

Убрал питон - теперь система совсем сдала сбой. Т.е. С дебианом только из офф.репов. Так?

Вопрос мой вот в чем: посоветуйте дистриб, где разрешено установить пакеты не только из офф. Репозиториев.

**Либо.**

Подскажите метод установки, при котором установить пакеты так, чтоб не рушить систему , если такое возможно, конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можешь пакеты ставить от куда хочешь.Установить питон и кьют (выполнять от рута):aptitude install python2.7 python-qt4

Всё что нужно должно потянуть в зависимостях.Если какая-то ошибка в пакетах то об этом напишет, если не запустится IDE Eric то нужно смотреть логи, что ему не хватает.